# Python Stream Waveform output into Database

Tags: python, redhawksdr

I am looking how to take data from a waveform component and write it to a db. I looking for some example of hooking to the waveform port and decode the BulkIO in to some python native data structure that I can then use to write to a db.

I tried looking at the Python-Rest example with no such look and the stub in manual only expexts a single port not multiple ports.

It does not need to be done using Corba but there is even less documentation on how to read data from the TCP stream

Any Help Be Most appropriated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the REDHAWK python sandbox to create an `sb.DataSink` and connect that to your Component or Waveform's output port. You can then read data from the `sb.DataSink` and get back SRI, timestamps, and data to send into your DB however you choose. You can write this is as a simple python script if that is what suites your application.

If your application will need to interact with the database you could look into using a REDHAWK python service. This way your REDHAWK application can interact with the REDHAWK service and is part of your REDHAWK domain.

The [REDHAWK enterprise](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/enterprise) tooling may be of use but is java & apache camel rather than Python but should have tooling to pipe data from RH to a number of different external sources including databases.